# Create a release area in Clearcase 7.1.2

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

How to create a release area for users to install the IBM Rational Clearcase v 7.1.2 Client with specific site definition, so that developers can connect to the Clearcase server(which is already installed and setup) from clients desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention in "[Creating a release area](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_ms_install_win.doc/creating_a_release_area.htm)", when you install IBM Rational ClearCase, you first create a networkwide release area. Then install the product on servers and clients from release area you have created.

But that is for CC7.0 or 6.0 only: see "[Comparing pre-7.1 install technologies to new technologies in 7.1 for achieving enterprise deployment on Windows systems](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21398877)":

> **The pre-7.1 release area is referred to as a repository in 7.1**.
>   The **repository** might be a shared directory on a machine acting as a file server or a directory on a Web server. Repositories are read only.

So you need to create a **repository**: the all process is now managed by the **[Installation Manager](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/install/v1r4/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cic.commandline.doc/topics/t_imcl_install.html)**.

In that repository, you can:

- create a clearcase_response file, following the process in "[Unix ClearCase 7.1 silent install by example](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21391294)" (similar for Windows),
- or record your own ("[Recording a response file](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_record_response_file_IM_walkthrough.htm)"),
- or using one of the pre-defined example response file at "[Sample response files for IBM Rational ClearCase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21351501)".

In that response file, you will be able to specify the registry server and the license server names, as well as the region for the Vobs.

Comment: I have installed the Clearcase server already and didn't create the release area at that time. Now if I want to create it for CC client to be installed on developers desktops, what should i do? Do i need to just unzip the Client software and place this modified sample response file in place and installed?

Comment: @vchitta are the client on Unix or Windows?

Comment: on Windows only. Fyi, Server is also on windows box.

Comment: @vchitta then see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21398877: what was called "release area" for 7.0 or 6.0 ClearCase versions is now called a "repository". You would use the Installation Manager for creating a repo: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/install/v1r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cic.commandline.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_imcl_install.html (command line or GUI if you want), you can use UNC paths (for all you clients to access): http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/install/v1r6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.silentinstall12.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_unc_path.html.

Comment: @vchitta And you can record your own response file: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_record_response_file_IM_walkthrough.htm . Key point: all installation process now use the Installation Manager.

Comment: @vchitta I have updated the answer for CC7.1 repository and IM (Installation Manager) instead of CC.70 "release area".